# using drupal_add_js in php code drupal 7

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, drupal-7

I want to add javascript to a single page.  In php block code using the existing module

```
<?php 
   drupal_add_js('js/leagueSettings.js');
?>
```

I have a js folder in the modules/php directory where this specific module is.

I have tried using script tags also to no avail.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/leagueSettings.js"></script>
```

leagueSettings.js is simply

```
(function ($) {
alert('here');
})(jQuery);
```

I have tried it with only the alert..doesn't matter. I have tried using the **DIR** magic constant in place of the path.. nothing.

Anything I am missing?

EDIT---SOLUTION

```
//becuase the php block is 'php' module...
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'php') .'/js/leagueSettings.js');
```

Comment: Where are you using `drupal_add_js()` in your code?  As in, what function or hook?  Also, be sure to read the documentation very carefully http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the path `js/leagueSettings.js` is probably not working.

`drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'your_module_name')`

If your js is in a module you can add it using the syntax above.

The same thing goes for `<script>` tag.  the `src` needs to be correct.

also https://drupal.stackexchange.com/ is a great resource if you haven't checked it out yet.